# Custom fonts in blackberry cascades using qml

Tags: fonts, qml, blackberry-10, blackberry-cascades

From blackberry 10.2 I can use ***FontFaceRule*** like below to use custom fonts. But I need it to support from 10.0. Is there any way to do this? If not, is it atleast possible that I can check the sdk version in qml so that if the sdk version is > 10.2 it should import bb.cascades 1.2 and include fontface rule. My project is currently set to base sdk 10.0 so importing anything greater than 1.0 throws error.

```
TextStyleDefinition {
    id: myLabel
    base: SystemDefaults.TextStyles.BodyText
    fontWeight: FontWeight.Bold
    textAlign: TextAlign.Center
    fontSize: FontSize.PointValue
    color: Color.create("#FFFFFF")
    fontSizeValue: 12
    rules: [
        FontFaceRule {
            id: styleFontRule
            source: "asset:///fonts/Montserrat-Bold.ttf"
            fontFamily: "Montserrat-Bold"
        }
    ]
}
```

## EDIT

```
attachedObjects: [
 FontLoader {
                id: fixedFont;   source: "asset:///fonts/Montserrat-Bold.ttf"
            },

TextStyleDefinition {
        id: myLabel
        base: SystemDefaults.TextStyles.BodyText
        fontWeight: FontWeight.Bold
        textAlign: TextAlign.Center
        fontSize: FontSize.PointValue
        color: Color.create("#FFFFFF")
        fontSizeValue: 12
        fontFamily: fixedFont.source
    }
}]
```

Comment: Why don't you use FontLoader instead?

Comment: I did try Fontloader as above, but it shows error:FontLoader is not a type. Any suggestions??

Comment: what do you mean by "not a type" error? FontLoader is not an element in blackberry? I usually use fixedFont.name for font.family  in qml. Try to change fixedFont.source to fixedFont.name.

Comment: I tried that, still same error. Am I doing anything wrong? I have currently imported import QtQuick 1.0 is there anything else that I need to import.